# CSOM Powershell get the files of a specific folder in a document library

Tags: powershell, csom

I am wanting to get the list of files that are in a specific folder in that document library using powershell CSOM

Tried this but it didnt work saying it didnt recognise getfolder

```
$folder = $list.ParentWeb.GetFolder($web.Url + "/" + $list.RootFolder.Url + "/" + $foldername)
foreach ($item in $folder.Files) {
   Write-Host $item.Name
}
```

Comment: that isnt CSOM it doesn't work

Comment: The answer might not be correct, but it is the same question. Hence the duplicate mark

Comment: ah, i just saw the this question already has an answer sorry